# VueJS how do you create a functional component using x-templates?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I want to create a vueJS functional component with a template as a single-file component. I am using x-templates so my component would be in a .html file.

For example, how do I turn the following component into a functional component?

```
<!-- my_component.html -->
<script type="text/x-template" id="my-component-template">
    <div>
        blah blah blah
    </div>
</script>

<script>
    Vue.component('my-component', {
        delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
        template: '#my-component-template',
        props: {},
    })
</script>
```

I can only find examples of how to do so if I were using .vue files in which case you would use `<template functional>`. How do you do the same with x-templates?

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Functional-Components):

```js
Vue.component('my-component', {
  functional: true,
})
```

Comment: when I add `functional: true,` I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined"

Comment: I don't know, it doesn't sound related to functional components.